# How do I find out which system unit is causing nologin not to be removed?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

My machine is not booting and I have tracked it down to GDM not starting because is says there is a nologin file. How can I find out what is causing this to not be deleted? All systemd units have started.

Comment: A more fully described question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335189/5132 .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to tell you what caused it, but you might be able to go into a recovery mode and mount up what's needed to manually delete `/etc/nologin` which is the file that would cause this. If it comes *back*, then there's more debugging to do.

Comment: It will come back all of the time because that is how systemd operating systems work.  A `/run/nologin` file is created at system startup, and later removed.  The contents of the file, which should have been supplied in this question to show the reason for prohibiting login, actually state that the "system is booting up" in such a case.